# how find nearest latlong in mongodb + yii

Tags: mongodb, yii

i use yii framework and mongodb database.
my database user table like this:

```
"latlon": {
     "lat": "23.022505",
     "lon": "72.571362"
  }
```

i use below query:

```
$taxi = new EMongoCriteria;
$taxi->latlon = array('$near' => array(floatval(23.038417),floatval(72.528802)));
$model_user = User::model()->findAll($taxi);
```

i want to result
"latlon": {
         "lat": "23.022505",
         "lon": "72.571362"
      }

Comment: There seem to be a few adapters for the framework so it probably comes down to which you are using. Basically you will want a method that accepts a MongoDB query in a "raw" form. At least you have ordered arguments as "longitude" and "latitude" as expected.

Comment: MongoDB will return $near already sorted by nearest

Comment: hii sammaye
      but i m not getting any data

Comment: Are you sure that items should be returned? Can you maybe edit the question with some sample documents?